# Angular 2: Display image in div

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular-template

How do you display image in div? In my case, it is from the database.

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results" class="search-res" (click)="showEmployee(result._id)">
     <div><img class=""/> {{ result.name }} </div> 
</div>
```

The image's name is `result.profile_picture`. How do you add it in the html?

Comment: Your html cannot magically creates an image and display it out of nothing. Either you provide an image url, or you provide the image byte datta arary (encoded), then the browser can display the image

Comment: does `result.profile_picutre` contains path or just name? If it is just name then what is the path?

Comment: `<img [src]="result.profile_picture>`?

Comment: You will need to specify the contents of `result.profile_picture`. Does the property contain an image **URL**? Is it a **base64** string or data uri? The simplest answer would be using @torazaburo 's answer above, assuming it is indeed a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display your image directly into a div you can add a CSS property with NgStyle:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results" class="search-res" (click)="showEmployee(result._id)">
   <div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + result.image_path+ ')'}">> {{ result.name }} </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why would I use this clumsy `ngStyle` approach instead of just saying `[style.background-image]="'url(' + result.image_path + ')'"`?

Comment: I didn't know your approach

Answer (score 1):

you can display image like this. does this help.

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results" class="search-res" (click)="showEmployee(result._id)">
     <div><img src="{{result.profile_picture}}"> {{ result.name }} </div> 
</div>
```